# How to get content of a tag without class, id, name?

Tags: vb.net

I need to get the content of the "a" tag in a webpage. The html code is this:

```
<ol class="sugg" id="user-list">
<li><a title="TEST" href="javascript:void(0)">X1</a></li>
<li><a title="TEST" href="javascript:void(0)">X2</a></li>
<li><a title="TEST" href="javascript:void(0)">X3</a></li>
<li><a title="TEST" href="javascript:void(0)">X4</a></li>
<li><a title="TEST" href="javascript:void(0)">X5</a></li>
</ol>
```

I have to catch the first "a" content that in this case is "X1".

Answer (score 0):

First Add your Project [HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

```
Dim document = New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()
document.Loadhtml("http://youraddress")
Dim original As String = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//ol[@id='user-list']/li/a").InnerText
MsgBox(original)
```